# Umbraco not loading context menus - could not be resolved to a .Net object type

Tags: menu, tree, contextmenu, umbraco, umbraco7

I've got pretty big problem and I think this is since I installed Umbraco as I never updated.

I just can't access quite a lot of menus (right-click menus) like republish or culture and hostnames or languages or some of create.

I checked 2 browsers (Chrome and Firefox) - none of them working.

I'm working on Umbraco 7.4.3 assembly: 1.0.5948.18141

In log files I'm getting something like:

"2017-05-16 07:14:01,363 [P17884/D18/T227] WARN  Umbraco.Core.Services.ApplicationTreeService - The tree definition:  could not be resolved to a .Net object type"

Also I can add that I'm getting pretty lots of logs with problem that secure connection cannot be established as I'm currently working locally on self-signed certificate and I've got rule in web.config that redirects to https but even if I comment it and run on http it still doesn't let me access culture and hostnames. So far I never changed hostname to https as I can't access it.

I'm pretty sure the problem is with trees.config but I don't know how to fix it so I'm attaching this here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trees>
  <!--Content-->
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="content" application="content" title="Content" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.ContentTreeController, umbraco" />
  <add initialize="false" sortOrder="0" alias="contentRecycleBin" application="content" title="Recycle Bin" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.ContentRecycleBin, umbraco" />
  <!--Media-->
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="media" application="media" title="Media" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.MediaTreeController, umbraco" />
  <add initialize="false" sortOrder="0" alias="mediaRecycleBin" application="media" title="Recycle Bin" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.MediaRecycleBin, umbraco" />
  <!--Settings-->
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="documentTypes" application="settings" title="Document Types" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.ContentTypeTreeController, umbraco" />
  <add application="settings" alias="templates" title="Templates" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.TemplatesTreeController, umbraco" initialize="true" sortOrder="1" />
  <add application="settings" alias="partialViews" title="Partial Views" silent="false" initialize="true" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.PartialViewsTree, umbraco" sortOrder="2" />
  <add application="settings" alias="stylesheets" title="Stylesheets" type="umbraco.loadStylesheets, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="3" />
  <add application="settings" alias="stylesheetProperty" title="Stylesheet Property" type="umbraco.loadStylesheetProperty, umbraco" iconClosed="" iconOpen="" initialize="false" sortOrder="0" />
  <add application="settings" alias="scripts" title="Scripts" type="umbraco.loadScripts, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="4" />
  <add application="settings" alias="languages" title="Languages" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.LanguageTreeController, umbraco" sortOrder="5" />
  <add application="settings" alias="dictionary" title="Dictionary" type="umbraco.loadDictionary, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="6" />
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="7" alias="mediaTypes" application="settings" title="Media Types" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.MediaTypeTreeController, umbraco" />
  <!--Developer-->
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="dataTypes" application="developer" title="Data Types" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.DataTypeTreeController, umbraco" />
  <add application="developer" alias="macros" title="Macros" type="umbraco.loadMacros, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="2" />
  <add application="developer" alias="packager" title="Packages" type="umbraco.loadPackager, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="3" />
  <add application="developer" alias="packagerPackages" title="Packager Packages" type="umbraco.loadPackages, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" initialize="false" sortOrder="3" />
  <add application="developer" alias="relationTypes" title="Relation Types" type="umbraco.loadRelationTypes, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="4" />
  <add application="developer" alias="xslt" title="XSLT Files" type="umbraco.loadXslt, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="5" />
  <add application="developer" alias="partialViewMacros" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.PartialViewMacrosTree, umbraco" silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="6" title="Partial View Macro Files" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" />
  <!--Users-->
  <add application="users" alias="users" title="Users" type="umbraco.loadUsers, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="0" />
  <add application="users" alias="userTypes" title="User Types" type="umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.UserTypes, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="1" />
  <add application="users" alias="userPermissions" title="User Permissions" type="umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees.UserPermissions, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="2" />
  <!--Members-->
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="member" application="member" title="Members" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.MemberTreeController, umbraco" />
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="1" alias="memberTypes" application="member" title="Member Types" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Web.Trees.MemberTypeTreeController, umbraco" />
  <add application="member" sortOrder="2" alias="memberGroups" title="Member Groups" type="umbraco.loadMemberGroups, umbraco" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" />
  <!--Translation-->
  <add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="1" alias="openTasks" application="translation" title="Tasks assigned to you" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="umbraco.loadOpenTasks, umbraco" />
  <add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="2" alias="yourTasks" application="translation" title="Tasks created by you" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" type="umbraco.loadYourTasks, umbraco" />
  <!-- Custom -->
  <!--<add application="myApplication" alias="myTree" title="Me Tree" type="MyNamespace.myTree, MyAssembly"
       iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder" sortOrder="10" />-->
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="2" alias="datasource" application="forms" title="Datasources" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Forms.Web.Trees.DataSourceTreeController, Umbraco.Forms.Web" />
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="0" alias="form" application="forms" title="Forms" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Forms.Web.Trees.FormTreeController, Umbraco.Forms.Web" />
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="3" alias="prevaluesource" application="forms" title="Prevalue sources" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Forms.Web.Trees.PreValueSourceTreeController, Umbraco.Forms.Web" />
  <add initialize="true" sortOrder="3" alias="formsecurity" application="users" title="Forms Security" iconClosed="icon-folder" iconOpen="icon-folder-open" type="Umbraco.Forms.Web.Trees.FormSecurityTreeController, Umbraco.Forms.Web" />
</trees>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys I found problem:

I checked client side and I had X-Frame-Options=DENY in web.config.

If anyone have similar issue try using SAMEORIGIN instead of DENY